# I can't use firebase because of quota (however I didn't reach it)

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage

**EDIT:** I really don't know what just happened right now but I was still looking over the dashboard for some other infos and the statistics just reseted! I'm sorry for posting! **For anyone wondering, I think the quotas reset at 10 AM (EET)**

I'm working on a work certificate in informatics and I decided to give Firebase a try with this project. I love it :)

Two days ago, when I started, everything was good. Yesterday at 8 PM I think I reached the quota for bandwidth (1GB) so I said, "ok no problem, I'll work on it tomorrow". Now today when I opened Firebase Console I still get this error in Storage: "You have exceeded your quota for this project. Please upgrade your plan."

I will leave here a few screenshots with my statistics. Can anyone help me figure out why my limits did not reset? PS. The error first showed up at maybe 8 PM yesterday and now it's 10 AM. It's another day but 24 hours didn't pass. Is this the real reason? I read on another StackOverflow question that it resets daily so I thought that at 12 AM it resets.

Thanks in advance!

[image]

You can see in this picture that on 15 December (yesterday) I have 1GB hit but on 16 December (today) is 0.

[image]
However, if I set the calendar to show me "Today" instead of "Current billing period" it shows me that the bandwidth was used today

So my question is, the quota is working on a 24 hours base or daily base?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

read [the fine print](https://firebase.google.com/pricing/) ...it reads `1 GB per day` for Storage.

it does not tell when it resets - and might eventually depend on the zone & region.

try to use smaller files for testing purposes.